# Bras and kets question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, notation, complex-numbers

If a state $|\psi\rangle$ can be written as a linear combination of the orthonormal states $|\phi_{n}\rangle$ as:

$|\psi\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}|\phi_{n}\rangle$

then is it valid to write:

$\langle\psi|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}\langle\phi_{n}|$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks elementary research.

Answer (score 8):

Almost: it should be $\langle\psi|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}^\ast\langle\phi_{n}|$.